# Nodejs express: how to use common function needed by different routes logic

Tags: node.js, express, routes

How can I add common methods/functions that can be used by different routes built using express in nodejs?

I created a nodejs server that is currently serving 3 APIs. For example:

```
/cars
/cars/:id
/cars/:id/sellers
```

All these 3 APIs retrieves data from another external APIs. So, I already have some code that is similar in all of those routes. For example, sending a GET request to the external API endpoint but with different parameters.

For the last API in my list above, I want to enhance it so that it will take optional paramters (lastname, firstname). I could have another API endpoint like this:

```
/cars/:id/sellers/:lastname&:firstname
```

But in this case the logic for this and the 3rd API in my list will be almost identical.

I'd like to create some util functions that I can call from any of my API routes with different parameters. I'm not quite sure to do this or where to begin.

Any suggestions?

Comment: For us to offer any specific advice, you'd have to show us the code you're using that you'd like to factor out common functionality.  The generic answer is that you figure out what functionality is common among your routes, create a function to carry out that operation and then call that function from each of your routes.  This is no different for routes than for any other Javascript code.  Since you're calling an external API, your common function would probably return a promise that lets the caller know when it's done or if it had an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  //req.someParam
  //your logic
  next();
});
```

You can use a middleware like this make sure to add it after your routes has defined, it will work as a common middleware in the routes

```
 router.post('/cars', (req, res, next) => {
    // if() some condition
    req.someParam = "param";
    next();
 });
```